# Optimization of code in javascripts JSON calls

Tags: php, jquery, json, zend-framework, ember.js

I've been involved in a large web application where I have a lot of functions that calls web services through JSON. For instance:

```
/*...*/
refreshClientBoxes: function(customerNr) {
        var request = {};
        request.method = "getClientBoxes";
        request.params = {};
        request.params.customerNr = customerNr;
        request.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
        postObject(jsonURL, JSON.stringify(request), successClientBoxes);
    },   

/*...*/
```

Where “postObject” it’s a function that receive an URL, the data and a callback.

As you can see I have to construct this piece of code in every single method:

```
    var request = {};
    request.method = "getClientBoxes";
    request.params = {};
    request.params.customerNr = customerNr;
    request.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
```

What's change is the name of the method that we will call and the name and values of parameter that we want to pass.

So I was wondering if there is a way that we can avoid this effort through a method that receive the name of the method that we will call and array of parameters, and using some kind of reflection construct the request parameters and return the request stringifyed.

For the WS I used php + zend 1.12, the MVC framework in JS its ember 0.95 and jQuery.

**Edit 1:** So thanks all for your answers. What I want it's a way that can give me the name of the parameters that I'm passing to the function or the name of a variable that I passed. Something like this:

```
var contructRequest = function (methodName, paramList) {
    var request = {};
    request.method = methodName;
    request.params = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < paramlist; i++){
       /*some how get the paramName through reflection...so if i give a variable called customerNr  this "for" add this new parameter to list of parameters like request.params.customerNr = customerNr whatever the variable name is or its value*/
    }
    request.params[paramName] = paramValue;
    request.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    return request;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a method like this:

```
var contructRequest = function (methodName, paramList, paramName, paramValue) {
    var request = {};
    request.method = methodName;
    request.params = paramList;
    request.params[paramName] = paramValue;
    request.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    return request;
}
```

This exploits the fact that `object.property` can also be referred to using `object["property"]`.

You can call the method like so:

```
var customerRequest = constructRequest("getClientBoxes", {}, "customerNr", customerNr);
postObject(jsonURL, JSON.stringify(customerRequest), successClientBoxes);
```

Comment: When you sat request.params["paramName"], the "paramName" it’s the same as paramName in the function? You know how to get the name of a variable in JS or jQuery... That could solve my problem... Thanks

Comment: You mean `request.params[paramName]`, not `request.params["paramName"]`.

Comment: @MattBall, oops, I'd written this in a hurry! I've edited my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You could DRY this by encapsulating the common parts in a separate function which takes the non-common parts as arguments, and returns the JSON. For example, if we assume that the only parts that change across the different functions are the `method` and `customerNr`:

```
buildRequest(method, customerNr) {
    var request = {
        method: method,
        params: {
            customerNr: customerNr
        },
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
    };
    return JSON.stringify(request);
}
```

and you'd use it like so:

```
refreshClientBoxes: function(customerNr) {
    var json = buildRequest('getClientBoxes', customerNr);
    postObject(jsonURL, json, successClientBoxes);
},
```

Comment: But there it’s the same problem because I have other function that has others parameters like customerAccount or phoneNr etc. 

What I want it’s a way, maybe with reflection, that could construct the request like the example above.

Comment: Why? I don't see why it's a "problem." It might help if you edit the question to add another example or two, explaining exactly what you're trying to solve.